# Parallelismus in "meint Michael Ramm, Soziologe und verantwortlich für die Studie"

Tags: usage, style, parallelism

Aus [DW](http://www.dw.de/zu-viel-lernen-zu-wenig-engagement/a-18062650):

> „Es gibt […] eine gewisse Umfragemüdigkeit“, meint Michael Ramm, Soziologe an der Universität Konstanz und verantwortlich für die Studie.

Wenn man die Person zugleich mit dem Nomen **Soziologe** und dem Adjektiv **verantwortlich** beschreibt, ist die Konstruktion meiner Meinung nach nicht parallel. Kommt dieser Stil üblich vor?

Comment: Ist meiner Meinung nach völlig in Ordnung (und in Zeitungsartikeln durchaus nicht unüblich).

Comment: "Schlechter Stil" ist eine subjektive Eigenschaft and als Frage schwer objektiv zu beantworten. Nach meinem Stilempfinden ist die Konstruktion völlig in Ordnung.

Comment: Ich sehe da keinen Parallelismus (zumindest in dem Sinn wie er in der Wikipedia beschrieben ist ;) ). Beide Aussagen könnten für sich stehen und wiederholen weder Satzstruktur noch Inhalt. Ist deine Frage nun ob es sich hier um eine parallele Konstruktion handelt oder ob diese generell schlechter Stil sind?

Comment: Ich würde schon sagen unüblich. Üblicher wäre: "... meint  Ramm, Soziologe und Verantwortlicher für die Studie".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es handelt sich hier um eine komplexe Apposition<sup>[(1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919034511/http://www.konrad-duden.info/?Rechtschreibung:Appositionen)(2)</sup>, für die ich aber keine Regel finden kann, dass sie als oben genannte "und"-Konstruktion ungültig wäre. Dieser Stil ist jedenfalls üblich. Parallelität spielt hier keine Rolle, warum auch?